# Complete the square of a multivariable function

Tags: linear-algebra, completing-the-square

I have a quadratic form which I have mostly completed the square but I am stuck at the final stage.

Currently it is in the form:

$\frac{1}{2}\left(x+4y\right)^2+4\left(y+z\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(x+2z\right)^2-6y^2-5z^2$

I'm hoping to get in the form :

$\left(x+a\right)^2+\left(y+b\right)^2+\left(z+c\right)^2$ with a change of variables so I guess it will more be $x'^2+y'^2+z'^2$.

Comment: Just realised the formatting is out! Fixing now!

Comment: Your hope is not a rational hope. You would need to make a linear change of variables to accomplish that. How do the cross-terms (i.e., $xy$, $xz$, $yz$) magically vanish in thin air? But you shouldn't have 5 square terms, just 3. The $-6y^2$ should have been incorporated before you got to the $yz$-stuff. And the $xz$ terms should have been incorporated into the first term ... $(x+4y+2z)^2$ ...

Comment: As @TedShifrin points, your expected form is unreachable, look at [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cleft%28x%2B4y%5Cright%29%5E2%2B4%5Cleft%28y%2Bz%5Cright%29%5E2%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cleft%28x%2B2z%5Cright%29%5E2-6y%5E2-5z%5E2).

Comment: If you haven't learned the correct way to do this problem, you might check out my [YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQPWoz4KBiE&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=47).

Comment: Crikey, great lecture! Got it now thanks alot!